# Unchanging/constant variable in python after reseting discord bot?

Tags: python, pycharm, discord, discord.py

I was wondering if there some function or module in Python that would allow me to create variables that don't get changed back to 0 when I restart my Discord bot? I have many minigames where you earn points for completing them and my solution for now has just been to type the user ID in a file and then if the user wants to see how many points they have, it just counts the amount of the ID in the file. But it looks bad, so if there is some other solution; for example, if had a variable `score = 0` so I could just write `score += 1` and it won't change after restarting the bot.

[image: Here is how it looks in file]

Code just for example how bad it looks:

```
# Some code
if score_1 > score_2:   
    await msg.send(msg.author.mention + " **You have won**. You have earned 3 points.")
    tabulka = open("tabulka.txt", "a")
    tabulka.write("\n" + str(msg.author.id))
    tabulka.write("\n" + str(msg.author.id))
    tabulka.write("\n" + str(msg.author.id))
    tabulka.close()
    on_command = 0

@bot.command()
async def me(msg):
    if msg.channel.id != channel:
        return
    message = str(msg.message.content)
    id = msg.author.id
    tabulka = open("tabulka.txt", "r")
    data = tabulka.read()
    result = str(data.count(str(id)))
    await msg.send(msg.author.mention + " Your score is: " + "**" + result + "**")
    tabulka.close()
```

Comment: I am not sure about what is bot. Why you do not write the results in a database or file?

Comment: Oh sorry there was a mistake, i meant file, not list and also the bot is discord bot, But my point is that its just awful solution in my opinion so i was asking if there is some way to create constant variable that wouldnt get changed after restarting the program.

Comment: If you need to keep that value after restarting the **program** then you do need a file to save it. Look for the file and the value at the start and initialize `score` depending on what you could read there. Don't forget a default behavior if the file does not exist or the value cannot be found.

Comment: Agree with @Guimoute. A file is ok, a database would be perhaps a proper solution. Still do not know what is a discord bot, but I guess is not relevant for this question

Comment: Yeah it doesnt matter what is discord bot. I mean this solution is fine, it works but i was just wondering if there is some another way how to to that, but thank you guys anyway.